# Debian 10 login loop fix?

Tags: debian, login

I am desperately trying to install openjdk-17 to my Debian 10 VM (with UI) and when I was setting the environment variables I found a [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13046624/how-to-permanently-export-a-variable-in-linux) with script to set the variables permanently. After running the script and restarting the VM using the script I can't get past the login screen anymore (after typing password the screen goes black and flashes once and gets back to the login screen).

The script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Enter variable name: "
read variable_name
echo "Enter variable value: "
read variable_value
echo "adding " $variable_name " to environment variables: " $variable_value
echo "export "$variable_name"="$variable_value>>~/.bashrc
echo $variable_name"="$variable_value>>~/.profile
echo $variable_name"="$variable_value>>/etc/environment
source ~/.bashrc
source ~/.profile
echo "do you want to restart your computer to apply changes in /etc/environment file? yes(y)no(n)"
read restart
case $restart in
    y) sudo shutdown -r 0;;
    n) echo "don't forget to restart your computer manually";;
esac
exit
```

Also, I have used Linux before but still I use it with the skills of a five-year-old. How do I solve this issue? None of the methods I find online seems to be working for me / I don't use them properly.

Thanks.

Comment: How did you previously run the script before login stopped working?  Unless you configured the script to run automatically at login, it is likely the script added something to your startup files that is causing your issue.  You would probably need to examine the contents of `~/.bashrc`, `~/.profile`, and `/etc/environment` to see if there is anything in those files that could be causing your loop.

Comment: @GracefulRestart I just made a script file and ran it manually two times for each variable (JAVA_HOME and PATH) after the last variable the script restarted the machine and after that I couldn't login through the UI anymore. I can still login using command line. How do I know if the contents of the directories you mentioned are causing the problem? Is there a reference what the directories should look like?